# How to initialize instance of a class using another object pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, constructor

I have a code where in

```
   class Passenger;

   class Reservation {
           std::string coach;
           int seat_number;
           Passenger * traveller;
   public:
          Reservation (Passenger * pas, std::string coch, int seat);
          void showReservation();
  };
```

and then defining the functions

```
Reservation::Reservation(Passenger * pas, string coch, int seat) : coach(coch), seat_number(seat) {
           traveller = new Passenger(pas);
   }
```

This shows an error, when I am doing this.

It will work if instead of using `*` I use `&`. I want to initialize the new object traveller with the `pas` value. How to do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for `traveller = new Passenger(*pas);` In all likelihood, there's no reason for `Passenger * traveller;`, it should be `Passenger traveller;`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two ideas here. Either you want to copy the pointer:

```
traveller = pas;
```

Or you want to do a deep copy of the object:

```
traveller = new Passenger(*pas);
```

Whichever you want depends on how you want `Reservation` used. Does it own its own `Passenger` or not? It seems like a `Reservation` shouldn't own a `Passenger`, so likely that first one is what you want.

Note that this could be clearer if you used smart pointers to express ownership:

```
class Reservation {
    std::string coach;
    int seat_number;
    std::shared_ptr<Passenger> traveller;

    // etc.
};
```